# How do I make my join paramater return more than one object in the response?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, postman

I have 3 models: `team`, `developer` and `message`.
I've been trying to receive a response to a request I send to an endpoint (`/trigger_notification`) like this:

```rb
 Response
      {
          team_id: "team_id",
          sms: {
              id: "ARANDOMID", 
              mobiles: ["numer1","number2"]
              content: "the content of this message", 
              sent_at: "18:54:34 IST 2021"
          },
          email: {
              id: "ARANDOMID", 
              emails: ["email1@email.com", "email2@email.com"]
              title: "Used in emails for title",
              content: "the content of this message", 
              sent_at: "18:54:34 IST 2021"
          }
      }
```

While most of the response works just fine, the `mobiles` and `emails` specifically aren't retrieving all the assigned developers. This should be done when creating a new team with the following request params and some additional optional params in case you also want to create a new developer using nested attributes:

```rb
Adding “developers” from the Team API creates developers as well

        {            
            "name": "Core Backend",
            "dept_name": "Engineering",
            "dev_ids": [id1, id2, id3, id5],
            "developers":[        
                {
                  "full_name": "Some Name",
                  "email": "same.name@example.com",
                  "mobile": "1234567890"
                },
                {
                  "full_name": "Other Name",
                  "email": "other.name@example.com",
                  "mobile": "9876543210"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Specifically `dev_ids` is used to note the id of the devs included in a team (since they have an HMT association with each other). I created a separate join table to enable this functionality that is separate from the one used for the `has_many through:` association called `memberships`:

```rb
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :developer
end
```

So, I create a team and set the `dev_ids: [3, 4]`.
However, I still find that the response ends up looking more like this:

```rb
{
    "Response": {
        "team_id": 3,
        "sms": {
            "id": "6cefeed1-f0c2-47c0-83cd-1db764e0acae",
            "mobile": [],
            "content": "This is a test message.",
            "sent_at": "2021-10-12T12:51:30.620+05:30"
        },
        "email": {
            "id": "cfddd984-ded0-40dd-badc-42d6694a5d92",
            "email": [],
            "title": "Test Message #5",
            "content": "This is a test message.",
            "sent_at": "2021-10-12T12:51:30.620+05:30"
        }
    }
}
```

For a few where I created the developer and the team together, it gives a response like this.

```rb
{
    "Response": {
        "team_id": 2,
        "sms": {
            "id": "435887a7-3729-4b35-b75f-10784a9d056c",
            "mobile": [
                "1234567890"
            ],
            "content": "This is a test message.",
            "sent_at": "2021-10-12T12:52:22.629+05:30"
        },
        "email": {
            "id": "8e4a642c-2008-42b7-b2f8-77319fb7a71e",
            "email": [
                "pierceb@gmail.com"
            ],
            "title": "Test Message #5",
            "content": "This is a test message.",
            "sent_at": "2021-10-12T12:52:22.629+05:30"
        }
    }
}
```

Controller for this action:

```rb
trigger_controller.rb

class TriggerController < ApplicationController
    require 'securerandom'
    def notification
        @message = Message.new(message_params)
        @id = params[:team_id]
        @content = params[:content]
        @title = params[:title]
        # @mob = Team.joins(:developers).where(team_id: @id).pluck(:mobile)
        # @mob = Team.joins(:developers).pluck(:mobile)
        # @mob = Team.includes(:developers).find(@id).pluck(:'developers.mobile')
         @mob = Team.find(params[:team_id]).developers.pluck(:mobile)
        @mail = Team.find(params[:team_id]).developers.pluck(:email)
        tim = Time.now

        if @message.save
          respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render json: { 'Response' => {:team_id => @id, 
                'sms' => { "id" => SecureRandom.uuid, "mobile" => @mob, :content => @content, "sent_at" => tim }, 
                'email' => { "id" => SecureRandom.uuid, "email" => @mail, :title => @title, :content => @content, "sent_at" => tim } } } }
          end
        else
            render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end

    end


    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_message
      @message = Message.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def message_params
      params.permit(:team_id, :title, :content)
    end
end
```

Models:

```rb
team.rb

class Team < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, presence: true
    has_many :messages
    has_many :developer_teams
    has_many :developers, through: :developer_teams
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :developers
end

developer.rb

class Developer < ApplicationRecord
    validates :full_name, presence: true
    has_many :developer_teams
    has_many :teams, through: :developer_teams
end

message.rb

class Message < ApplicationRecord
    validates :title, presence: true
    belongs_to :team
end
```

Controller for team:

```rb
team_controller.rb

class TeamsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_team, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /teams
  def index
    @teams = Team.all

    render json: @teams
  end

  # GET /teams/1
  def show
    render json: @team
  end

  # POST /teams
  def create
    @team = Team.new(plus_params)

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      # if plus_params.has_key?(:dev_ids)
      #   @team.developer_ids << Developer.find(plus_params.dev_ids)
      # end

      # if plus_params.has_key?(:developer_attributes)
      #   @team.developers << Developer.insert_all(plus_params.developer_attributes)
      # end

      @team.save!
    end

    render json: @team, status: :created, location: @team
  rescue
    render json: @team.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end


  # PATCH/PUT /teams/1
  def update
    if @team.update(team_params)
      render json: @team
    else
      render json: @team.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /teams/1
  def destroy
    @team.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_team
      @team = Team.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def team_params
      params.require(:team).permit(:name, :dept_name, dev_ids: [])
    end

    def plus_params
      params.require(:team).permit(:name, :dept_name, dev_ids: [], :developers_attributes => [:full_name, :email, :mobile])
    end
end
```

Here's what the log usually shows when I send a request at the `/trigger_notification` endpoint:

```
Started POST "/trigger_notification" for ::1 at 2021-10-12 13:01:16 +0530
Processing by TriggerController#notification as */*
  Parameters: {"team_id"=>6, "title"=>"Test Message #5", "content"=>"This is a test message.", "trigger"=>{"team_id"=>6, "title"=>"Test Message #5", "content"=>"This is a test message."}}
Unpermitted parameter: :trigger
  Team Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/trigger_controller.rb:11:in `notification'
   (1.0ms)  SELECT "developers"."mobile" FROM "developers" INNER JOIN "developer_teams" ON "developers"."id" = "developer_teams"."developer_id" WHERE "developer_teams"."team_id" = $1  [["team_id", 6]]
  ↳ app/controllers/trigger_controller.rb:11:in `notification'
  CACHE Team Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/trigger_controller.rb:12:in `notification'
   (0.4ms)  SELECT "developers"."email" FROM "developers" INNER JOIN "developer_teams" ON "developers"."id" = "developer_teams"."developer_id" WHERE "developer_teams"."team_id" = $1  [["team_id", 6]]
  ↳ app/controllers/trigger_controller.rb:12:in `notification'
  CACHE Team Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/trigger_controller.rb:15:in `notification'
  TRANSACTION (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/trigger_controller.rb:15:in `notification'
  Message Create (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "messages" ("team_id", "title", "content", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["team_id", 6], ["title", "Test Message #5"], ["content", "This is a test message."], ["created_at", "2021-10-12 07:31:16.420140"], ["updated_at", "2021-10-12 07:31:16.420140"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/trigger_controller.rb:15:in `notification'
  TRANSACTION (7.7ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/trigger_controller.rb:15:in `notification'
Completed 200 OK in 37ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 12.2ms | Allocations: 5075)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are quite a few issues with this code.  In your `#create` method you are indescrimately rescuing every type of exception. Its just completely off the mark - use `if @team.save ... else ... end` instead since invalid input is not an exceptional event and this pokemón exception handling will make debugging a nightmare.

Comment: The next issue is that your at the point where your JSON responses are getting complex enough that you need a serialization layer - this can either be something like ActiveModel::Serializers, jBuilder or even a plain old ruby object. https://thoughtbot.com/blog/better-serialization-less-as-json

Comment: Changed the `create` method as per suggestion.

Oh, interesting, do serialization layers simplify JSON responses? I was wondering if it could solve the issue with `dev_ids` I'm having by having it pass by a different format.